# Adding own HTML element and custom CSS in Vaadin application

Tags: java, html, css, vaadin

I'm creating a web application in Vaadin. I found there is a possibility to add custom layout with CSS or create your own theme to existing vaadin component. Is there a possibility to **add your own html element** and **css** **in Vaadin** application? If yes, how can You achieve it? (Java 8, Intellij IDEA)

Comment: It depends what do you wish to achieve. But adding CSS to vaadin is just a matter of adding it to sccs styles, html as you mentioned to the custom layouts (or via Label in html rendering mode)

Comment: I created simple news-ticker in pure HTML and CSS and try to add it to my application (that mostly contains vaadin elements). So You think about custom layout like: https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/layout/layout-customlayout.html?

Answer (score 2):

Among other things, you can write HTML and CSS directly by setting the content mode of a label to HTML:

```
Label label = new Label("<p style='background: yellow;'>Test</p>");
label.setContentMode(ContentMode.HTML);
```

Comment: If you ever re-display user entered text inside your HTML here make sure you cleanse it otherwise you might be opening up your application to XSS etc...

Comment: Cross-site scripting :( Actually not a bad idea to write inside a label, but my css is a little bit complicated with many animations so it would require additional work to rewrite it to one html file :(

Comment: *EDIT* Forgot about internal CSS style- it's easy to make html out of html + css, i will try this for short-term purposes if i won't find better solution :)

Comment: Vaadin has pretty extensive support for CSS: https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/themes/themes-creating.html